# how to continue animation and uitimer in background

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, timer, background

I have a stop watch-like app. When I hit the start button the timer() is triggered to start counting every second and i have a uiView that rotates 360 degrees through uiview.animation and continues to rotate until i hit the stop button.

However, when i minimize my app my animation for my uiview stops. The timer() stops counting while its in the background to but continues on once the app is brought back up. But the uiview doesn't even continue rotating, that one actually stops completely.

Anyways, I need everything to run smoothly even while it is in the background. Heck, even when the screen is off/locked. Its a stop watch, so you could assume why.

Please help!! Thanks!

Swift Only

Answer (score 0):

Capture and save the start time and duration by writing it to UserDefaults or some other persistent storage (don't forget to remove it when the timer is complete).

Register for the notification NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground .  When you get this notification, compare the current time to the start time + duration.  If its past the endTime show some message to that effect.  Otherwise recreate your timer based on the remaining time and restart your spinner animation.